# Athena Query to match Alpha numeric Character at a fixed length in a colum data

Tags: sql, hive, presto, amazon-athena, trino

In AWS Athena, how should i write query to get column values when the values is `A-Z` after dot`'.'`.

List of Column Values are :

```
DT90411.A7
CT90411.23 
CT90411.Q3
```

Currently i am not able to fetch value that have `A-Z` characters after dot`'.'`

Expected result :

```
DT90411.A7 
CT90411.Q3
```

These have characters `A-Z` after dot`'.'`

```
Select Col_A from Table1 where Col_A  like '%.[a-z]%'; is not giving the desired result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regexp_like.

Demo:

```
with Table1  as(
SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
        'DT90411.A7', 'CT90411.23' ,'CT90411.Q3' 
) AS t (Col_A )
)
  
select Col_A
from Table1 
where regexp_like(Col_A,'(i?)\.[A-Z]')
```

Result:

```
Col_A

DT90411.A7
CT90411.Q3
```

Regexp `'(i?)\.[A-Z]'` means:

`(i?)`  - case insensitive, remove it is you need case sensitive match

`\.`    - dot

`[A-Z]` - character class, letters A to Z

Comment: Thanks a lot.. this helped getting the desired result